# flatten group by columns with correct order

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['a','a','a','b'],"item1":['b','d',np.nan,'c']})
df_grp=df.groupby("item").agg({'item1' : ['last','count']})
df_grp.columns = df_grp.columns.map('_'.join)
df_grp.reset_index()
```

This gives me

```
  item item1_last  item1_count
0    a          d            2
1    b          c            1
```

What I want

```
  item last_item1  count_item1
0    a          d            2
1    b          c            1
```

is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `swaplevel` before joining the columns.

```
df_grp.columns = df_grp.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)
#df_grp.columns = df_grp.swaplevel(axis=1).columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
df_grp.columns = df_grp.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)
print(df_grp.reset_index())

  item last_item1  count_item1
0    a          d            2
1    b          c            1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with `f-string`s:

```
df_grp.columns = df_grp.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
```

Or swap them in list comprehension:

```
df_grp.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df_grp.columns]
```

---

```
print (df_grp)
     last_item1  count_item1
item                        
a             d            2
b             c            1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option with named agg:

```
df_grp=(df.groupby("item", as_index=False)
          .agg(last_item1=('item1', 'last'),
               count_item1=('item1','count'))
       )
```

Output:

```
  item last_item1  count_item1
0    a          d            2
1    b          c            1
```